# How to mount samba share on NAS at boot the same way it is mounted by "Files"?

Tags: samba, fstab

*Before you mark this as duplicate kindly read on.*

I have a samba share on a NAS that is mounted only when I click on it in `Files`.

[image]

The share is mounted as

`/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=mycloudex2ultra.local,share=public`

I would like the NAS to be mounted exactly like that, but at boot. What should I write in the `/etc/fstab`?

Instructions I have found are to mount the share in a directory under `/media` which is not what I am trying to do. Also, I don't know where the file with samba credentials is, if anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure that /run/user/1000 even exists "at boot" does it? AFAIK it's created on the fly by pam_systemd (and destroyed when the user has no more concurrent sessions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount the smb share at boot by adding this line to `/etc/fstab`

```
//server/shared /path/to/mount cifs credentials=/path/to/creds.txt 0 0
```

For what your case seems to be:

```
//mycloudex2ultra.local/public /path/to/mount cifs credentials=/path/to/creds.txt 0 0
```

Also create a file `/path/to/creds.txt` and do `chmod 600 /path/to/creds.txt` with the following content:

```
username=Username
password=Password
domain=DomainName
```

You can read more through redhat's documentation here:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/managing_file_systems/index#mounting-an-smb-share-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux_managing-file-systems

The documentation would be very similar to Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I really think you would be better off with a traditional CIFS mount as outlined by **Killian Fortman's** answer.

But if you absolutely need to have it mount like Nautilus does it then this example might work:

I created a file in my Ubuntu home directory: /home/tester/ServerCreds with this content:

```
guest
workgroup
dummypassword
```

*I'm accessing a guest share that doesn't require credentials but gvfs demands I pass one anyway so I made something up.*

Then go to Activities > Startup Applications > Add

```
Name: ServerPublicShare
Command:  bash -c 'gio mount smb://vxub2204.local/public < /home/tester/ServerCreds'
```

When I logoff and login again the share is mounted and available in Nautilus:

```
tester@vub2204:~$ ls -l /run/user/1000/gvfs
total 0
drwx------ 1 tester tester 0 Feb  7 06:56 'smb-share:server=vxub2204.local,share=public'
```

Comment: I didn't manage to make the change to Startup Applications work, the command doesn't seem to know what vxub2204 is. I ended up taking your advice and @killian-fortman 's advice and used a traditional cifs mount.